# It is the same $f(x):=x^2\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty(\cos x)^k$ than $g(x):=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty x^2(\cos x)^k$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

It is the same $f(x):=x^2\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty(\cos x)^k$ than $g(x):=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty x^2(\cos x)^k$?

It seems that $f(0)$ is not defined because $\sum_{k=0}^\infty 1^k=\infty$, however $g(0)=0$! There is something wrong with this reasoning or this is a case where normal arithmetic fails with series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are **almost** the same.  They are the same except when $x=0$.

If $x=0$ then all terms in $g(x)$ are zero, so $g(0)$ exists and equals $0$.  But the definition of $f(0)$ says:
$$
f(0) := 0^2\;\sum_{k=0}^\infty (\cos 0)^k
$$
which is zero times a divergent series.  So $f(0)$ is **undefined**.

Now, it is true that $f(x)$ has a removable discontinuity at zero.  So for most purposes setting $f(0)=0$ is what you want anyway.

**added**
Let me put here another example.  Define
$$
h(x) := \big(1-\cos x\big)\;\sum_{k=0}^\infty (\cos x)^k
$$
Now for $-\pi < x < \pi$ except $x=0$ we have $h(x) = 1$, yet for $x=0$ we have the same undefined
$$
h(0) := 0\;\sum_{k=0}^\infty (\cos 0)^k
$$
Now the natural value is $h(0)=1$.  The difference between $f(0)$ and $h(0)$ is an illustration of the **indeterminate form** $0 \cdot \infty$.

Comment: so you are saying that the accepted answer is not correct?

Comment: @Masacroso... Yes, I am saying that.  Shanye2020 used the "fact" that the limit of the product is the product of the limits.  But that is only correct if both limits exist.

Comment: Yes, I understand. We cant make algebra with something that is not defined in this algebra, right?

Comment: I'm curious, isn't $f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow0} x^2\sum_{k=0}^n(\cos x)^k$ for every x in the domain?

Comment: @QWERTZ ... For every $x$ in the domain of $f$, yes.  But of course $x=0$ is in the domain of $g$ but not of $f$.

Comment: Wait, f is defined as $f(x):=x^2\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty(\cos x)^k$ which means (and I think this is the point where I miss something) $f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow0} x^2\sum_{k=0}^n(\cos x)^k$. This should imply that the partial sums evaluated at 0 are all 0.

Comment: @QWERTZ ... You gave (something equal to) the definition of $g$.  The definition of $f$ is a product of two things.  And the second factor $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (\cos 0)^k$ does not exist for $f(0)$.

Comment: @GEdgar I got it, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing particularly special about $\sum_{k=0}^\infty(\cos x)^k$ per se, this is more to do with if you accept the following equation or not:
$$
0+0+0+\dots =0(1+1+1+\dots)
$$
Yes, strictly speaking the value on the right hand side is not defined since $1+1+\dots$ diverges, but sometimes it is convenient to set it to be $0$. This convention is used many places in analysis, e.g. measure theory.

Answer (score 3):

They are same. The key is to remember that:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k
\end{align*}
If you consider the sequence:
\begin{align*}
(a_n) = \{0^2\cdot1, 0^2\cdot(1+1), 0^2\cdot(1+1+1), \cdots\} = \{0, 0, 0, \cdots\}
\end{align*}
You will see that for each $n\in \mathbb{N}, a_n = x^2\sum_{k=0}^{n}\cos^k(x)$, when $x = 0$. This shows that:
\begin{align*}
f(0) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x^2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos^k(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}0 = 0
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Yes they are the same. As the sum is only over the parameter $k$ you can treat the $x^2$ as a constant (it doesn't change with $k$) and factorize or expand it as you have done.

Comment: but $\sum_{k=0}^\infty 1^k=\infty$ so it seems that $f(0)=0\cdot\infty$.

Comment: As you have noticed odd things happen at $x=0$. To try to define it at $x=0$ you need to take a limit not just substitute in $x=0$.

Comment: $f(0)$ is $0$ because all the partial sums are $0$

Comment: In both cases if you take the limit as $x\to0$ you get a value of $2$.

Comment: @Ian why 2? Isn't $f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow0} x^2\sum_{k=0}^n(\cos x)^k$ for every fixed x?

Comment: I must confess I didn't bother to check the math and just let [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5BSum%5Bx%5E2*Cos%5Bx%5D%5Ek,+%7Bk,+0,+Infinity%7D%5D,+x+-%3E+0%5D) do the heavy lifting. I suspect it comes out of L'hopital but haven't checked. Note my limit is $x\to0$ as opposed to your $n\to0$.

Comment: right @QWERTZ !!

Comment: The question now is: Why Wolfram Alpha gives 2?

Comment: It probably is more appropriate to take treat it as $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}x^2\sum_{k=0}^n(\cos x)^k$

Comment: Because of the change of order of the two limits. The way I entered it into WA forced it to do $k$ first then $x$ as opposed to the opposite order.

Comment: @ Ian You are right